# Storing and manipulating HTML strings in Android

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to dynamically generate some HTML that my app needs to output.
The setup is a base HTML string, which contains a list - the content of the list will change from time to time.
I'm not sure about how to store HTML string properly in an Android app. Just storing it as a string does not seem to work as the " signs in the HTML are breaking the string. What I wish to achieve is something like this:

```
<html>
  <h1 style="color:blue;">Title</h1>
  {some generated HTML code here}
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</html>
```

The actual HTML is obviously a lot longer and more complex but for simplicity I have just created some dummy HTML.

Can someone guide me towards a way of handling something like this in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) to manipulate HTML string in a proper way.

```
val doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString)
Element div = doc.select("div").first(); // <div></div>
div.text("five > four"); // <div>five &gt; four</div>
div.prepend("First ");
div.append(" Last");
```

Now create a basic HTML document which you can edit dynamically like this and return as output.